# Zoom pop-up to center screen from center of clicked div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am new for jQuery and all, forgive me If I am wrong anywhere.

I have a requirement, that there are multiple click-able boxes, as soon as you click on any box it will open like pop-up but in such a manner It will look like it is coming out from that particular clicked box, and if you will close the opened pop-up, it will shrink to the clicked box(look like it is going inside the clicked box)

Comment: Bro.. first u need to post some html to show us what you have tried. I hope you aren't new to HTML atleast. Show us the exact or piece of design you have already..

Comment: I think it's no a real question, but this may help you: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: This is still an open question. If you still need help, please comment below an answer with more information.  ***If solved, please close the question*** by (a) choosing a correct answer *by clicking checkmark beside an answer*, or (b) by posting your own answer and selecting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a complex question for a jQuery novice, but here is a solution.

> Caveat: In a rush and don't have time just now to calculate the correct coords to position the pop-up box dead center of screen - **this example puts the top/left corner of the box dead center of screen.** I leave it to you to work out the coordinates to put center of box in center of screen -- *and I would appreciate it if you would leave a comment with link to revised jsFiddle with your solution.*

<kbd>[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fkqefs2w/)</kbd>

```js
 var xx, yy, mPos = { x: -1, y: -1 }; //mouse position
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
 mPos.x = event.pageX;
 mPos.y = event.pageY;
});

$('.dd').click(function(){
 xx = mPos.x;
 yy = mPos.y;
 $('#msg').css({top:mPos.y+'px',left:mPos.x+'px'}).animate({
  height: '400px',
  width: '500px',
  left: $(window).width() / 2,
  top: $(window).height() / 2
 },500,function(){
  //use a callback to show overlay ONLY when animation finished
  $('#overlay').show(); 
 });
});
$('#msg').click(function(){
 $('#overlay').hide();
 $('#msg').animate({
  height: '0px',
  width: '0px',
  left: xx+'px',
  top: yy+'px'
 },500);
});
```

```css
#overlay{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;background:black;opacity:0.7;z-index:1;display:none;}
#msg{position:absolute;height:0;left:0;background:wheat;overflow:hidden;z-index:2;}

.dd{height:30px;width:100px;margin:30px;padding-top:25px;border:1px solid orange;}
.clickable{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="msg">Click on me to minimize again</div>

<div id="d1" class="dd clickable">Div One</div>
<div id="d2" class="dd clickable">Div Two</div>
<div id="d3" class="dd clickable">Div Three</div>
<div id="d4" class="dd clickable">Div Four</div>
```